# Redirect to same route with different parameter values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a situation that I am working on a blogging website which has urls of the form:

/blog/{id}/{title-slug}

The {title-slug} is purely a user friendly string designed to make the url look nicer. The id alone is enough to uniquely determine everything.

I have some code in a global ActionFilterAttribute which will recognise that the {title-slug} is missing (or incorrect) and it then does

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url.Action(action, controller, routeValueDictionary));
```

This works mostly fine except for one problem. I have multiple routes that match the controller and action and it seems to just choose the first one...

Lets see some code. My relevant routes look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute
(
    "ShowFeedAndFollow",
    "blog/{shortcode}/{slug}/followme",
    new { controller = "Public", action = "ShowFeed", shortcode = "", slug = "", followme = true } // Parameter defaults                
);

routes.MapRoute
(
    "ShowFeed",
    "blog/{shortcode}/{slug}",
    new { controller = "Public", action = "ShowFeed", shortcode = "", slug = "" } // Parameter defaults                
);
```

My code to redirect if the slug is wrong looks (in simplified form) like this:

```
var slug = filterContext.RouteData.Values["slug"] == null ? "" : filterContext.RouteData.Values["slug"].ToString();
var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] == null ? "" : filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
var controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] == null ? "" : filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
RouteValueDictionary routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens);
var canonicalSlug = GetCanonnicalSlug();
routeValueDictionary["slug"] = canonicalSlug;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(canonicalSlug) && !slug.Equals(canonicalSlug))    
{
    var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url.Action(action, controller, routeValueDictionary));
}
```

As you can see I can get the action and controller from the current route data and make a new routeValueDictionary with the modified route data. The problem I have is that it picks up the url for the first route (called "ShowFeedAndFollow") and not the one I actually want and that it came in as, "ShowFeed".

I cannot hardcode the route name (because the same code currently works for blogs and posts in the blogs). I have the route object (`filterContext.RouteData.Route`) but I can't seem to find a way to generate a url given that object.

I can probably just reorder the routes so that the one I want is first. However this is clearly a fragile solution that breaks if I ever decide to do something that changes the order of these things.

So my question in summary then is this:given I am in a filter attribute and have all the data about the route that got me here and I want to just redirect to the exact same route/url but with one parameter changed, how can I best do this?

Comment: Potentially, yes. But that presumably still just leads me down the path of hardcoding which I'd hoped not to have to do. And as I mentioned (somewhere in that wall of text) this same logic is getting used for a couple of things and I also have old routes that are now obsolete and are identical except for the actual url (ie we used to use `/bongoblog/{shortcode}/{slug}` and the route still exists for people with old bookmarks). I'm hoping for something more elegant stemming from the fact that I have the route object and the route dictionary without needing lots of checks...

Answer (score 0):

To do the routing with parameters in *filterContext* it will be better to use *RedirectToRouteResult* instead of *RedirectResult*

You can simply do this:

First collect all route data include Controller Name, Action Name and other parameters.

```
var routeData = filterContext.RouteData.Values;
```

Then make any change that needed in parameters like this:

```
routeData["slug"] = routeData["slug"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
```

and finally use **RedirectToRouteResult** instead of **RedirectResult**:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeData);
```